# nVidia - Display driver stopped responding and has recovered

Tags: windows-7, crash, nvidia-graphics-card, display-driver

[image: 1]

I keep getting this error of nVidia driver. So what it does basically first it freeze all windows then my monitor becomes black and if it recovers it gives me error message like u see in the url, if not then i just have to restart my pc. After error recovering my Photoshop closes, all websites remain black so i have to restart browser. I would love to know it there is any real solution for this, or why it's happening. I have newest drivers of nVidia.

I noticed that I get it more often when:

- Skype starts
- Working on Photoshop or other programs like Illustrator
- Viewing images
- Watching YouTube
- Playing some games

I'm on Windows 7. Here is my dxdiag Display tab:

[image: 2]

Comment: have you completely uninstalled and reinstalled your nvidia drivers? what kind of video card are you using? Do you have DirectX installed, and do you use a common codec package?

Comment: I have nVidia geForce 450 GTS, yes i've reinstalled drivers of nvidia before fully uninstalled old ones, but about driectX and codec packages idk...which ones should i choose?

Comment: I had the same error notice and many similar symptoms when the video card in my laptop started going bad.  It's a severe fix, but replacing the card and reinstalling the drivers fixed it (I had reinstalled the drivers before w/o changing the card with no noticeable effect).

Comment: well, all your trouble vectors focus on video or intense image rendering, which means lots of binary decoding, so Codecs are a possible explanation of the problem, and a potential solution though its a longshot. I tend toward the Shark 007 codec pack for win7 boxes. have you run 'dxdiag'? http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Run-DirectX-Diagnostic-Tool

Comment: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=inv80h&s=6 here is my dxdiag, display tab.

Comment: Try getting a new Nvidia driver for your card on [driver](http://www.geforce.com/drivers) and do a manual search. See if the error is solved.

Comment: Official thread with no help from Nvidia: https://forums.geforce.com/default/topic/709328/geforce-drivers/nvidia-windows-kernel-mode-driver-335-23-stopped-responding-and-was-recovered-successfully/1/

Answer (score 0):

I just had a PC with a Nvidia card that was having the same issues, and it was because the power supply did not have enough juice to power the card. Check your PSU output rating and see if it is enough for what the card requires.

Answer (score 0):

read this KB Article and try the FixIt:

**"Display driver stopped responding and has recovered" error in Windows 7 or Windows Vista**
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2665946

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling your graphics card drivers usually fixes this issue. If you recently upgraded your PC I would make sure that your PSU can handle any upgraded or newly installed parts. I would also reseat your graphics card completely as it may have a loose connection. Unfortunately the error is pretty ambiguous but if the issue happens again you can check your system's event viewer for any notable errors that might give you some information (or at least post here and someone might be able gleam something from it).

Answer (score 0):

Once I had this problem too, and finally it is solved by enable page file (virtual memory). With enough physical RAM I disabled page file to protect SSD, but the system sometimes terminate games like RE7 or CoD:MWR, and later the system also have your issule even when using Chrome. The problem seems to be related to VRAM overload, although this should not happen since OS may emulate/page out VRAM with main RAM when VRAM is overloaded. The emulate/page out process of VRAM may be somehow related to virtual memory and then disabling virtual memory disturbs this process.

Later I re-enabled page file and put it to HDD, the problem never happens again for me.