# Display driver crashing on Windows 8 multi monitor with displayLink

Tags: windows-8, multiple-monitors, display-driver

I have a [Sony laptop](http://www.ldlc.com/fiche/PB00127837.html) (full specs around the bottom) with an AMD Radeon HD 6630M, sitting on a docking station plugged with 3 DisplayLink USB to DVI adapters connected to 3 screens in 1920*1200 in portrait mode. It's an i7, and I've added memory making it 12 Gigs, so I thought it'd be fine.

Anyway, I'm a web developper, and when I use Java apps such as Netbeans with long scripting pages and/or I do large mySQL imports I have my screen turning black very often, and reappearing after 5 secs, with an error message "Display driver stopped responding and has recovered" like in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/555335/nvidia-display-driver-stopped-responding-and-has-recovered). After a while it's really bothering. Considering the number of USB devices, I wondered if it couldn't be a power shortage problem but I have no clue how to test that.

I have turned off anti-virus/malware softwares, it didn't solve the problem.

[image: You can see Disk 99%, but I get to 20MB/s or more when I do a file transfer]
You can see Disk 99%, but I get to 20MB/s or more when I do a file transfer

It's SSD and there is no paging file for Windows. (problem remains when if there is one)

Any help would be wonderful.

Comment: I assume you have installed the Windows 8 driver.  We talking about Windows 8 or Windows 8.1?

Comment: And yes it's the driver for Windows 8, and I have 8, not 8.1

Answer (score 1):

Try the tips (newer drivers, higher TdrDelay value or reducing the visual effects) from this KB article and look if something helps.

**"Display driver stopped responding and has recovered" error**

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2665946/en-us

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't find the TdrDelay entry in Windows 8's registry, and can't find either any equivalent.

Comment: create the value (DWORD 32Bit) and set the value to 8.

Comment: under **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\GraphicsDrivers** as written in the KB article.

Comment: Thanks. I've added it, restarted, and got a crash later on, same message :(

Comment: increase the number to 10 or 12.

Comment: Thanks again. You confirm I stay on Hexadecimal base?

Comment: No, still the same. It takes longer now between the moments the screen stops responding and when it turns black...

Comment: have you tried different drivers?

Comment: No because the regular AMD driver doesn't install on my laptop, it tells me I should use my manufacturer's, which I do use.

Comment: have you tried the 13.11 Beta driver? http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/latest-catalyst-windows-beta.aspx

Comment: I just did. Crash during install, unable to restart Windows, had to use restoration. :(